# How do I define IList<T> in Interface

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, generic-programming

I have method readExcelFile() which takes parameter and generic type where generic type is class so the idea is give this method require parameter to read excel file and I get List of object having excel records.

The all is working fine that state above but I also need to define interface

```
public interface IProcessExcel 
{
    IList<T> ReadExcelFile(string filePath, int readExcelRowFrom, int headerRow);  
}
```

and in above code I am getting error

```
 The Type or namespace T could not be found(missing directive or assembly )
```

implementation code

```
 public class ProcessExcel<T>: IProcessExcel where T: class
{
    private static Excel.Application xlApp;
    private static Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
    private static Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    private static Excel.Range xlRange;
    private string GivenFilePath = string.Empty;        
    private IList<string> ExcelFileExtensionList = new string[] { ".xls", ".xlsx", ".xlsm", ".xltx", ".xltm" };
    private T newObject;
    List<T> ExcelRecordList = new List<T>();

    public ProcessExcel()
    {
    }


    public IList<T> ReadExcelFile(string filePath, int readExcelRowFrom, int headerRow) 
    {
        this.FilePath = filePath;
        this.ReadExcelRowFrom = readExcelRowFrom;
        this.HeaderRow = headerRow;
        this.ReferenceClass = typeof(T);
        this.ValidateExcelFile();
         this.ProcessReadExcelFile();

        return ReadExcelFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a generic interface as well

```
public interface IProcessExcel<T> where T:class
{
    IList<T> ReadExcelFile(string filePath, int readExcelRowFrom, int headerRow);  
}
```

The compiler doesn't know how to determine the `T` later.

The class then, will be defined like this:

```
public class ProcessExcel<T>: IProcessExcel<T> where T: class
```

Comment: that mean it changes implementation in implemented class!!

Comment: No, it doesn't. It will let you define `T` on instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the generic method correctly in **both** Interface and in Class
Like this :

`public interface IProcessExcel
{
    IList<T> ReadExcelFile<T>(string filePath, int readExcelRowFrom, int headerRow);

}`

Notice the declaration of 'T' after the Method Name.